# playing audio from a thread defined in a view class

Tags: android

How can I play an audio from a user thread that has been defined in a view class.This the portion of my thread from where i want to play the audio.

Thread:

```
if(a.n1==a.rightx&&a.n2>=a.topy&&a.n2<=a.bottomy||a.n2==a.bottomy&&a.n1>=a.leftx&&a.n1<=a.rightx)
    {

        audio.play(this,a.i);
        a.i+=1;
        int low=2;
        int high=8;
        int high1=10;
        float xlim=a.parentWidth*0.25f;
        int xright=(int)(xlim);


        a.n=a.r.nextInt(high-low);
        int xpos=a.r.nextInt(high1-low);
        a.n1=(xpos*10)+xright;
        a.n2=(a.n*60)+90;

        a.f1=(float)a.n1;
        a.f2=(float)a.n2;

        //Log.d("test","n1"+a.n1);
        //Log.d("test","n2"+a.n2);
    }
```

And this is my audio class:

```
  public class Audio{

public MediaPlayer mp=null;
public void play(Context context,int i)
{
    stop(context);
    //int resId=R.raw.button_1;
    //int x=i;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,i);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}
public void stop(Context context)
{
    if(mp!=null)
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that when i call the play method from the thread and pass this as an argument it shows me an error stating-The method play(Context, int) in the type Audio is not applicable for the arguments (DrawThread, int)

Comment: ".. it shows me an error." Show us the error as well, someone might be able to help.

Comment: @zalp this the error message-The method play(Context, int) in the type Audio is not applicable for the arguments (DrawThread, int)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line:

```
audio.play(this,a.i);
```

to:

```
audio.play(getContext(), a.i);
```

This is assuming your thread is created inside a custom view that extends android.view.View

```
public class DrawThread implements Runnable {
Context context;

public DrawThread (Context context)
{
    this.context= context;
}

public void run()
{
    if(a.n1==a.rightx&&a.n2>=a.topy&&a.n2<=a.bottomy||a.n2==a.bottomy&&a.n1>=a.leftx&&a.n1<=a.rightx)
    {
        audio.play(context,a.i);
    }
}
```

and from your View class:

```
Thread drawThread = new Thread(new DrawThread(getContext()));
drawThread.start();
```

Comment: the thread is called from a custom view.and when i use the getContext method do i also need to define it explicitly because it is giving an error "getContxt undefined for DrawThread"

Comment: Did you spell it correctly in your actual code? getContext() not getContxt.

Comment: Can you show the code for your entire thread?  Is it in a class all by itself?  If it is a class all by itself then you will have to pass context into the thread.  Be careful though as this can cause memory leaks as the thread will keep the context alive.

Comment: I am afraid the code is to large to post it all here.But yes the thread is a separate class all by itself.How should i pass context into thread?

Comment: I added code to my answer to show you how to pass the context to a thread in a separate class.

Comment: 07-27 00:39:31.337: W/dalvikvm(787): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-27 00:39:31.342: E/AndroidRuntime(787): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
07-27 00:39:31.342: E/AndroidRuntime(787): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:39:31.342: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at org.example.pacman.Audio.stop(Audio.java:23)
07-27 00:39:31.342: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at org.example.pacman.Audio.play(Audio.java:12)
07-27 00:39:31.342: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at org.example.pacman.DrawThread.run(GameView.java:283)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34259/discussion-between-user1236327-and-user2586942)

Comment: did you get my message??As i think i am still not elligible to chat on this site.

Comment: 12th line of audio.java is stop(context)

Comment: 07-27 01:30:06.739: W/dalvikvm(275): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-27 01:30:06.744: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
07-27 01:30:06.744: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 01:30:06.744: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
07-27 01:30:06.744: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at org.example.pacman.Audio.play(Audio.java:15)
07-27 01:30:06.744: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at org.example.pacman.DrawThread.run(GameView.java:289)